# Check if next element has specific class else go to next section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a script to scroll down to the correct section.
This is a small piece of the html code:

```
<div class="page_sections sectionOne">
    <div class="product_options">          
        <input />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="page_sections sectionTwo">
    <div class="product_options">          
        <input />
    </div>
    <div class="product_options">          
        <input />
    </div>
    <div class="product_options">          
        <input />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="page_sections sectionThree">
    <div class="product_options">          
        <input />
    </div>
    <div class="product_options">          
        <input />
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea of the script is whenever someone clicks on an input(all selects and radio's) to go to the next product_options. If no product options is found then go to the next section.

I think im pretty close but can't seem to finish it. Can you help me out:

```
$(".page_sections :input").change(function(){    

    var next = $(this).closest(".page_sections").nextAll('.page_sections').first();

    if ($(this).closest(".product_options").next('.product_options').length){
        next = $(this).closest(".product_options").next('.product_options');
    }        

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(next).offset().top - 180
    }, 1500);
});
```

I was really close. Made a typo with lenght -> length...

Comment: you misspelled `length`: `next('.product_options').lenght`, also no need for `$(next)` next is already a jquery object

Comment: Goddddd.... Thank god there's stackoverflow. Been staring for hours. Thanks @PatrickEvans

Answer (score 0):

I made a typo. Thanks for @PatrickEvans for pointing me to that!